# How can I use multiple account to check authority in anchor test?

Tags: anchor, anchor-test

For signing transactions, there is only one account (provider.wallet). I have written a program and it has some authority access functions, how can I use multiple accounts to check it?
If I generated new ones they gave me signature verification failed error..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your additional keypairs have no SOL to pay for tx fees. You can request an airdrop for them as follows:

```
const wallet = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();

const tx = await connection.requestAirdrop(
    wallet.publicKey,
    anchor.web3.LAMPORTS_PER_SOL * 1
  );

const latestBlockHash = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();
await connection.confirmTransaction({
    blockhash: latestBlockHash.blockhash,
    lastValidBlockHeight: latestBlockHash.lastValidBlockHeight,
    signature: tx
});
```

After this, you should be able to sign & pay for transactions with these keypairs.

Answer (score 1):

Generate wallet address and make airdrop
remove rpc() from function calls and use solana/web3.js methods

const wallet = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate()

```
const tx = await connection.requestAirdrop(
    wallet.publicKey,
    anchor.web3.LAMPORTS_PER_SOL * 1
  );

const latestBlockHash = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();
await connection.confirmTransaction({
    blockhash: latestBlockHash.blockhash,
    lastValidBlockHeight: latestBlockHash.lastValidBlockHeight,
    signature: tx
});

    const tx = await prog.methods
      .func()
      .accounts({ account: wallet.publicKey })
      .signers([wallet])
      .transaction();
    await sendAndConfirmTransaction(prog.provider.connection, tx, [wallet])
```